# AJP configuration fails

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I am trying to connect to a TC app with the virtual host below.  The TC app works directly mysite.net:8080/mysite and serves the entire site from index to compute. However the configuration just gives the default apache2 page.  What am I missing, please?

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
 
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName mysite.net.localhost
 
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost
 
        ProxyPass "/"       "ajp://localhost:8009/mysite"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "ajp://localhost:8009/mysite"
 
        LogLevel warn
 
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.net_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.net_access.log combined
 
</VirtualHost>
```

Below is the server.xml change and both server have been rebooted

```
<!--connector enabled 210818-->
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Also I put a symlink in /var/www/html/vhosts/[sites-available.conf].  Still showing the default.  Prefix the default.html and shows the directory.

Comment: Virtual host configurations do not go in `/var/www/html/vhosts` on Apache ... and that would be a strange place to keep them. When using Apache, it's generally better to put virtual host configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, then use `sudo a2ensite {filename}.conf` to enable them. This ensures that Apache does all the heavy lifting ...

Comment: @matigo  I removed the symlink, ran a2ensite [filename].conf it said already enabled, restarted apach2 and same, just showing the ubuntu apache default page.  It is as straight forward as you instruct, what is wrong?